# $g(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-x)^{n-1}$ what is $g'(x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence

I have yet another multiple choice question.

> Let the function $g$ be given as $$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-x)^{n-1} $$
> with convergence radius $\rho$.
>
> We look at $0 \leq x<\rho$, what is the correct expression for $g'(x)$?
>
> 1. $g'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+2)(n+1)(-x)^n$
> 2. $g'(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n+1)(-x)^n$
> 3. $g'(x)=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1)(-x)^n$
> 4. $g'(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n+1)n(-x)^n$
> 5. The expression for $g$ is not a differentiabel function

**My attempt**

I have a theorem in my course text book that states for a function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ the following holds $$f'(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(x)$$
Using our function $g$ we get
$$g'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n-1)(-x)^{n-2} $$

But as you can see, I don't get a result that matches any of the answers above. I tried to reduce the expression algebraically but that didn't lead me anywhere. I have a feeling that it's answer $2$, but I'm not sure.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

1. by the chain rule: $((-x)^{n-1})'=-(n-1)(-x)^{n-2}.$
2. if $n=1$ , then $n(n-1)=0.$

Consequence: $g'(x)=- \sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)(-x)^{n-2}.$

Option $3$ is correct.

Comment: Change your index so the sum starts at 0 and you get option 3.

Comment: @ eyballfrog: thanks ..